# How to hash in CFMX_COMPAT in c#

Tags: hash, coldfusion, cryptography

An existing coldfusion website is to be converted to dot net.

In the coldfusion code, the password is hashed using its hash() function with no algorithm:

```
SomePassword = '#hash(fldPassword)#'
```

I found [this document](http://cfdocs.org/hash), saying the default encryption is

> CFMX_COMPAT: Generates a hash string identical to that generated by
>   ColdFusion MX and ColdFusion MX 6.1 (default).

There are some articles actually telling me how to decrypt.

> According to Macromedia, The ColdFusion Encrypt function uses an
>   XOR-based algorithm that utilizes a pseudo random 32-bit key based on
>   a seed passed by the user as a parameter to the function. The
>   resulting data is UUencoded.
>
> You'll need to uudecode the encoded value first
>   http://www.eggheadcafe.com/printsear...asp?linkid=351
>
> and then XOR it using the key it was encrypted with.
>   http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/La...deamessage.htm
>
> If you dont have the key - your wasting yuor time.

But, how to make it work? I don't think there is any key. All I can see is `'#hash(fldPassword)#'`. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: I believe hash() is designed as a 1-way function that is not supposed to be "decrypted" is it?

Comment: interesting, then why did Adobe/Macromedia named it `CFMX_COMPAT` when it was indeed just a `MD5`?

Comment: @Henry - Sounds like a documentation error. (Where is an errata when you need one? ;) The `hash()` default for MX6 was `MD5` - not `CFMX_COMPAT`. Plus it makes no sense that they would reduce the default to `CFMX_COMPAT`, of all things, in later versions. It is not even a hashing algorithm ..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compare password hashes between C# and ColdFusion (CFMX\_COMPAT)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714155/compare-password-hashes-between-c-sharp-and-coldfusion-cfmx-compat)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There are some articles actually telling me how to decrypt.

Hashing and encryption are not the same thing. Encryption can be reversed. You can recover the original value if you have the right key, etectera. Whereas hashing is a one way trip. Once hashed, the original value cannot be recovered. (Well .. in theory. Some of the weaker hashing algorithms have been broken.)  So you cannot "decrypt" a hashed value. But you can duplicate the obfuscated result string.

> I found this document, saying the default encryption is CFMX_COMPAT

Actually it refers to the default *algorithm*. However, I am not so sure that description is correct. (*Edit: As Rasmus correctly points out, it does say the default is MD5*) However, CF9/7 default to MD5 anyway. Even when the algorithm is `CFMX_COMPAT`. So in either case, a simple MD5 hash in C# would give you the same result.

ie These all produce identical results ie `098F6BCD4621D373CADE4E832627B4F6`.

```
    #hash("test")#
    #hash("test", "cfmx_compat")#
    #hash("test", "md5")#
```

Comment: Down voter please leave a comment. Given the examples above prove the answer is correct, I am curious what you think is wrong ...

Answer (score 3):

If I read the documentation correctly, CFMX_COMPAT hashing is just MD5.

So:

```
byte[] hash = MD5.Create().ComputeHash(fldPassword);
```

It should be easy to verify if you have access to a ColdFusion installation.

Comment: Thank you. I got two correct answers at the same time. I rewarded to @Leigh, simply because you have already got too high reputation score. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: Lol, I get the sympathy vote ;) I was going to say give it to Rasmus because he got the "default" right, and I did not. So +1