# ColdFusion's CFMX_COMPAT encryption algorithm

Tags: encryption, coldfusion

In reviewing some old coldfusion code, I've found several instances of data being encrypted with the CFMX_COMPAT algorithm via the encrypt/decrypt functions.

After searching around for a while, I've been unable to find what kind of algorithm this is. The docs mention that it is now the least secure method, but I'd like to know why that is.

(A couple of people elesewhere have suggested that it's just MD5, but that doesn't make a lot of sense as the data is being decrypted.)

Comment: FWIW: Agreed it is definitely *not* MD5. (I suspect that impression comes from the [hash](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c52.html) documentation which misleadingly states the default algorithm `CFMX_COMPAT` "generates a hash string identical to that generated by ColdFusion MX and ColdFusion MX 6.1". That does not mean `CFMX_COMPAT` and `md5` are equivalent.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is an XOR-**based** algorithm, but not a text-book one, so blanket XOR-algorithm answers are not correct (and have been applied to these CFMX_COMPAT questions incorrectly in the past).

For a detailed look at the source code to this proprietary XOR, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4627069/850882) to "Compare Password Hashes Between C# and ColdFusion", in which @Leigh (who also commented on one of these questions) helped provide an accurate port of the algorithm, lifted directly from the Railo source.

Comment: Thanks for posting a better answer. I had always heard it was a simple XOR. I guess in a sense it is, but not as simple as I was lead to believe. Regardless, of course, the correct answer, always, is "do not use CFMX_COMPAT"  :)

Answer (score 1):

It is a simple XOR algorithm. Technically it is crypto, but it is very, very, very, very, very weak crypto. I should have put a few more "very"s in there.

As I understand it, each bit of the plaintext is XOR'd against the next byte in the key, the result is the ciphertext.

So if we looked at everything in bits:

P: 1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  1

K: 0  0  1  1  1  0  0  1  0  1  0

C: 1  0  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  1  0

P = Plaintext

K = Key

C = Ciphertext

If you are not familiar with XOR, it works like this:

0    XOR    0   ->  0

0    XOR    1   ->  1

1    XOR    0   ->  1

1    XOR    1   ->  0

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely not MD5, as that's a hashing algorithm, not an encryption algorithm (as you point out).

I dunno what algorithm it uses, but your could decompile the relevant Java class in cfusion.jar and have a look. I doubt there's a better way of finding out than that. I doubt even if you open a support ticket with Adobe that they'd actually tell you.

Comment: You could just look at the [Railo source](https://github.com/getrailo/railo/blob/master/railo-java/railo-core/src/railo/runtime/crypt/CFMXCompat.java). There may be slight differences, but the general algorithm is the same.

Comment: Ah yeah! Forgot about that! Good suggestion.