# Decrypt Coldfusion CFMX_COMPAT Encryption in php

Tags: php, encryption, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I checked in the Stack Overflow archives and found several answers about how to decrypt a ColdFusion CFMX_COMPAT encrypted value. All of those post says its a simple XOR. But it doesn't work for me and its not decrypt the encrypted values.

Can anyone help on decrypting the CFMX_COMPAT encrypted values using php?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show the php code you used.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot help you with php, but it is a little more than a simple XOR. This [C# port](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4627069/104223) of [Railo's](http://wiki.getrailo.org/) [cfmx_compat](https://github.com/getrailo/railo/blob/f0da69a7ad62fe760e40d9cd880bdecfd38a51d7/railo-java/railo-core/src/railo/runtime/crypt/CFMXCompat.java) implementation shows the algorithm. I can confirm it works from java and C#.