# With what is the key padded in cfusion_encrypt in c# alternative?

Tags: c#, encryption, coldfusion

I found an answer to replicate the cfusion_encrypt function in C# from here...

[ColdFusion - cfusion_encrypt() and cfusion_decrypt() - C# alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22289179/coldfusion-cfusion-encrypt-and-cfusion-decrypt-c-sharp-alternative/22291776#22291776][1])

But the answer doesn't say with what the key is padded with to make it the same length as the clear text? Can anyone suggest what the key is padded with? And whether it is padded to the right or left?

Answer (score 2):

This provides more clarity on what the function does.

[cfusion_encrypt](http://www.barneyb.com/barneyblog/2005/10/28/cfusion_encryptcfusion_decrypt-udfs/)

The key is repeated a number of times until it is longer or equal to the length of the plain text.

Comment: +1. Though as noted in the comments of that thread, `cfusion_encrypt/decrypt` were also removed in the latest version of CF. Ideally it should be eliminated and replaced with true encryption, or hashing for passwords.