# Encrypt String in PHP the Same as ColdFusion

Tags: php, encryption, coldfusion

I wish to encrypt a string in PHP in the same way as ColdFusion.

The ColdFusion code (key was generated using *GenerateSecretKey('AES')* ):

```
<cfset encryptedData = encrypt('text', 'CJsP3yDcEM9RIwme53rAUQ==')>
```

Which results in (the result below should have two spaces at the end):

```
$8X"%DP
```

The closest I could come up with (forgive me - I know very little of encryption):

```
$cipher = 'AES128'; // assumed the default algorithm in CF is AES so this made sense
$ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher); // These two lines are because the AES ciphers demand an init vector
$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
$key = 'CJsP3yDcEM9RIwme53rAUQ==';
$data = openssl_encrypt($data, $cipher, $key, $options=0, $iv);
echo $data;exit;
```

But this didn't work as the initialization vector will be different each time.

Comment: If the `encrypt()` method is written how you have posted then the algorithm is not 'AES'. The default algorithm that ColdFusion uses when you do not specify one is called 'CFMX_COMPAT' and is horrible. The key is being generated using 'AES' but not the encryption itself (from what you have posted). [Encrypt documentation](https://cfdocs.org/encrypt)

Comment: That looks like old code and I'd strongly advise you *don't* duplicate it. The key is AES, but the encryption isn't (nor is it using an iv).  It's an [old non-standard algorithm called cfmx_compat](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Guide_to_Cryptography) . That algorithm isn't used anymore because it's insecure. Modern CF apps use standard (strong) encryption algorithms like AES. It's very simple to convert the CF code to use [one of those](https://cfdocs.org/encrypt), which would be compatible with openssl which also uses the standards.

Comment: @Ageax The code is very old and I can't change it unfortunately but need to replicate it in PHP .Thanks for the info though both!

Comment: @dVyper - You should consider what type of data is being handled and what are the possible consequences to your company of improperly securing that data. Because by choosing to use it in your application, the responsibility of failing to adequately secure the data now falls on your company as well.

Comment: @dVyper look at this answer provided by Leigh - https://stackoverflow.com/a/4627069/1636917  In it he explains some details about the CFMX_COMPAT algorithm.

Comment: @Miguel-F - IMO, before considering it, I'd question what data is involved, because if were something like cc's or PII using that algorithm would be ... bad :-)

Comment: @Ageax I absolutely agree with you.  That algorithm should never be used, for anything. I'm just trying to help the OP with the given question. No doubt they should be using something else for the encryption. 100% agree.

Comment: @Miguel-F - I'm torn between helping and screaming "Don't do it!" ;-) Seriously though, since the OP mentioned being unfamiliar with encryption, I figured they might not be aware of the potential liabilities either, with all the different regulations (PCI, GDPR, etc..).  Or that not algorithms are equal and cfmx_compat is the tinker toy of "encryption" algorithms. Just trying to help him make an educated decision.

Comment: (... cont'd That's not directed at you, just encouraging the OP to know what they're getting into :-)

Comment: Yep, all good points and no offense taken. I guess I was just thinking that the OP may be "stuck" with this old code that was using the bad encryption. The only way the OP can decrypt that will be by using the same bad encryption as before. Now I would hope that for any _new_ encryption being done they will use a better more modern algorithm.

Comment: Rather than reusing the same broken encryption for new encryption just to be able to decrypt older stuff, I'd probably write a new encryption routine and then plan some time to decrypt the old info with the old method and then re-encrypt it with the new method.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what version of ColdFusion is this? And like Ageax mentioned, what type of data is being encrypted? ?PII?

Comment: And for completeness: https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/Cryptographic_Storage_Cheat_Sheet.md