# Decrypting coldfusion encrypted string in PHP

Tags: php, encryption, coldfusion

I have a string encrypted in Coldfusion which needs to be decrypted in PHP for usage.

So i am looking for a method which corresponds to:

```
Decrypt(stringToDecrypt,"2450RDSET0C","CFMX_COMPAT","HEX")
```

Here,

`stringToDecrypt` =  the string to be decrypted,

`"2450RDSET0C"` = the seed that was used to encrypt the string

`CFMX_COMPAT` = encryption algorithm

`HEX` = encoding used

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-c-d/Decrypt.html

example string to be decrypted: `6A968A969DEB9A16549C61EE2EFE40A6515E`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714155/compare-password-hashes-between-c-sharp-and-coldfusion-cfmx-compat/4627069#4627069 https://github.com/getrailo/railo/blob/master/railo-java/railo-core/src/railo/runtime/crypt/CFMXCompat.java

Comment: How are the above links lacking?

Comment: Is this ColdFusion server still on? The easiest thing to do would be to use CF to decrypt your value, then re-encrypt it with PHP. Or use CF to reencrypt the field with an algorithm that can translate into PHP without the need to replicate CFMX_COMPAT. BTW, what kind of data are you encrypting?

Comment: Also, what do you expect `stringToDecrypt` to decrypt to?

Comment: Have you tried this one? https://github.com/awkwardideas/PHPCFEncrypt

Comment: @RRK just tried works perfectly, Thank you please feel free to answer.

Comment: `what kind of data are you encrypting`. Good question. The bounty may get an answer on how to do it, regardless of security, but the advice from owasp.org:  [".. DO NOT use the CFMX_COMPAT algorithms. Upgrade your application to use stronger cryptographic ciphers..."](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Guide_to_Cryptography).

Comment: I'd agree with the above. Yes, this can "technically" be done. But it's probably something that "shouldn't" be done. Don't replicate `CFMX_COMPAT`. It's weak and broken encryption, which is just about as effective as no encryption at all. Again, if you are able, I'd use the CF server to decrypt your field, then re-encrypt it using a stronger, more common algorithm. Outside of `CFMX_COMPAT`, it's fairly easy to transfer an encrypted string between different languages.

Comment: @roko I think you can answer it with how you used the library. I am not much of a PHP person. So it is better that you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use the following code to decrypt your example string.

```php
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use AwkwardIdeas\PHPCFEncrypt\Encrypt;

$stringToDecrypt = '6A968A969DEB9A16549C61EE2EFE40A6515E';
$key = '2450RDSET0C';
$decrypted = Encrypt::decrypt($stringToDecrypt, $key, 'CFMX_COMPAT', 'hex');
var_dump($decrypted);
```

```
$ php main.php
string(18) "SofortUeberweisung"
```

After installing the dependency with composer.

```
composer require awkwardideas/phpcfencrypt
```

Here's a GitHub Gist you can use to test with.

https://gist.github.com/AlexanderOMara/b9bb6ff2a57bd0cf61fa8f0823d9a2a0

Just run `composer install` first.

## NOTE: This encryption scheme is rather weak!

Hopefully you are using this decryption code as part of a migration process to move to a stronger encryption scheme, like AES (or a password hash like bcrypt if this is for passwords).

Comment: Nothing against the answer, but while you *can* do this - you shouldn't. As mentioned in the comments above, the algorithm is very weak and it's usage is not recommended. Decrypting and re-encrypting the values with a more standard algorithm is extremely easy, and would provide both better security and compatibility with other languages.

Comment: @Ageax Well, they're going to need to decrypt them before they re-encrypt them. Hopefully that's why they want to decrypt them. I'll make a note about this though.

Comment: It sounded like CF was the producer and php the consumer, so re-encrypting would need to take place on the CF side. Though it could done in either language. The more important take-away here is to avoid using CFMX_COMPAT going forward.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the update you added to the answer about the weak encryption.

Answer (score -1):

As @RRK already mentioned, try https://github.com/awkwardideas/PHPCFEncrypt. Looks like this is the library you are looking for.

From [a test case](https://github.com/awkwardideas/PHPCFEncrypt/blob/master/tests/Feature/DecryptStringTest.php):

```
$encoded = Encrypt::decrypt($password, $key, "CFMX_COMPAT", "hex");
```

But as others also already mentioned, it's better to get rid of this type of cryptography.